# PBR workflow - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: normal-map, pbr, roughness

I'm going through a tutorial on UV mapping in Blender 2.8 and I need some help. Why is my material glossy/reflective? I have a roughness map connected (greyscale non color), and I also have a normal map connected (non color, into normal map node, bump node, then into normal input.

Both the normal map, and the roughness don't seem to do anything. The wooden pallet looks shiny, and completely unrealistic. Just to add to this, I thought a normal map is a RGB file? Why do I have to set it to non-color?[image: PB]

Comment: Non-Color means that blender will not read the image using a color transform, but will keep it as data. The main difference is that if you read as color there will be a "gamma" curve, whereas in non color the information will be linear.